# Subscription Issue : Your order is being processes. Your item will be available in a few minutes

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app, in-app-subscription

app purchase. The payment was successfully working for the subscription. But I'm getting the error as your order is being processed, so your item will be available in a few minutes.

Comment: Can you post your Code and the exact Error Message?

Comment: Can you insert stack trace of your error to the question?

Comment: this is pending payment. you must proces this variant

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not an error, sometimes the chosen payment method requires a lot of time for validation, I have seen some case that takes up to 24 hours !